# div inside for loop just take first value argument jsp

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-mobile, javabeans

I am using jquery mobile with jsp I have a loop in jsp and a Div tag for popup, my problem is that just it takes first value every time it just prints fist value of the loop, if someone have an idea I really appreciated, thanks. this is my code for looping

```
<% for( i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {%>

<li><a href="showSubClasses.jsp?id=<%=result.get(i) %>"><%=result.get(i) %></a><a href="#option" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Edit</a>    </li>

<div data-role="popup" id="option" data-theme="d" data-overlay-theme="b" class="ui-content" style="max-width:340px; padding-bottom:2em;">
            <h3>Delete?</h3>
            <p>Do you want to DELETE Individual <u><h4><%=result.get(i) %></h4></u></p>
            <a href="showSubClasses.jsp?id=<%=result.get(i) %>"><%=result.get(i) %></a><!-- data-role="button"  data-theme="b" data-icon="delete" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">Delete</a> -->
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">Cancel</a>
        </div>

<% } %>
```

Comment: You are using `id="option"` in loop. IDs must be unique

Comment: popup is working, I am using it for deleting element in the list, but in the popup all the time gives me just the first element in the loop    <%=result.get(i)%> just take firt value of the loop it doesn't change.

Comment: what is the `result` here and how are you adding the values to it ? Have you tried printing it ?

Comment: result is a list in java bean methode I am printing it in jsp

Comment: Thank you I found it, you right the problem was popup id was the same just i changed the id of the popup with the loop